# Inserting multiple dropdownlist values in a field in database (ASP)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ado.net

I have three dropdownlist which values are to be inserted in one particular field in the database. But i am new to ASP.

This are my following codes:

```
    Dim strConn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnectionString").ConnectionString
    Dim myConn As New SqlConnection(strConn)
    Dim cmd = "INSERT INTO [IndividualWorkout] (WorkoutProgramName, WorkoutProgramPosted, WorkoutProgramDesc, IndividualWorkoutName, IndividualWorkoutTips, TimingID) VALUES (@WorkoutProgramName, @WorkoutProgramPosted, @WorkoutProgramDesc, @IndividualWorkoutName, @IndividualWorkoutTips, @TimingID)"
    Dim myCmd As New SqlCommand(cmd, myConn)
    myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WorkoutProgramName", TextBox1.Text)
    myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WorkoutProgramPosted", TextBox2.Text)
    myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WorkoutProgramDesc", TextBox3.Text)
    myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IndividualWorkoutName", TextBox4.Text)
    myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IndividualWorkoutTips", TextBox5.Text)
    myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TimingID", DropDownList4.SelectedValue.ToString())
    myCmd.Connection = myConn
    myConn.Open()
    myCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    myConn.Close()
```

Could anyone guide me/help me with the editing of the following code so that the 3 dropdownlist values which were selected will go in the TimingID.

Thanks

Comment: Do you want 3 values concatenated into one column?

Comment: How do you propose to put three values into one value? You can use a comma-delimited list in a string, or XML (overkill), or some wild hacking (not recommended), or simply add two more columns (recommended, if possible)

Comment: When concatenating, I generally avoid comma-delimiters because of potential conflicts with strings.  Consider pipes ("|") or some other character that you are certain won't appear in your values to be safe.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to concatenate the values, you can do it like this.

```
string s = DropDownList4.SelectedValue.ToString() + "|" 
    + DropDownList5.SelectedValue.ToString() + "|" 
    + DropDownList6.SelectedValue.ToString();
myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TimingID", s);
```

Then you will have to parse out the 3 values when you retrieve the data from that field with a .Split() or similar function.

Just as a note, it seems odd to have an ID field use concatenated strings. I'm assuming this field requires uniqueness, which seems at risk by using a combination of dropdown values.  Do you have that covered?

Comment: Thank for the help. I will it as i just got expose to asp. Lots of thing not really sure.

Comment: Good luck.  Consider what sq33g said above.  If you can modify the table design, you might just want to store the three fields separately and modify your indexes accordingly.  Also, if you need a unique ID field, you can create a separate identify field just for that purpose.